# Django UserCreationForm

Tags: django, forms

We have built our platform using django and created a custom user model for our usage.

Up until now our platform was invite only and now we want to open the invites to everyone.

I've modified our custom form and view for the user registration and everything is working, but we're facing one issue. When sending an invite if the user's email is not registered on our platform we create a new user for him and set a boolean to mark him as not active. When coming in with the invite everything works OK, but if the user goes directly to our page and opens the registration form we get the error that a user with this email already exists.

We're extending the CreateView and the UserCreationForm to implement our custom registration form, so I'm guessing I must override one of the methods in these classes but not quite sure which one, I've tried with the save method of the UserCreationForm but it doesn't seem to work, it pops up the error messages without going into that method.

Any ideas on how I could do this? The implementation required would be that we look if a user with that email exists and he is inactive then save the registration form elements and set him to active, otherwise just show the error message.

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
"""A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
fields, plus a repeated password."""
password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CustomUserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.fields.pop('username')

class Meta:
    model = DealCircleUser
    #fields = ('email', 'dob', 'first_name', 'last_name')
    fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name')

def clean_password2(self):
    # Check that the two password entries match
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
    password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
    if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
        raise forms.ValidationError ("Passwords don't match")
    return password2

def save(self, commit=True):
    exits = DealCircleUser.objects.filter(email=self.cleaned_data["email"]).exists()
    if exits:
        print('We have the user')
        user = DealCircleUser.objects.get(email=self.cleaned_data["email"])
    else:
        print('No user found')

    # Save the provided password in hashed format
    user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
    #check if there is a user already created with this
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

And the view is:

class RegisterUserView(CreateView):
    model = DealCircleUser
    template_name = 'register.html'
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('frontend_profile')
    invitation = None

```
def get_form(self, form_class):
    code = self.request.GET.get('code')
    if code:
        self.invitation = Invitation.validate_code(code)
    if not self.request.user.is_anonymous():
        form_class = InputEmailForm
        self.object = self.request.user
    form = super(RegisterUserView, self).get_form(form_class)
    form.fields['email'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
    if self.request.user.is_anonymous():
        if self.invitation and self.invitation.email:
            form.fields['email'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
        form.fields['first_name'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        form.fields['last_name'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
    form.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
    form.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'

    if self.invitation:
        form.initial['email'] = self.invitation.email

    return form

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    ret = super(RegisterUserView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    ret['twitterEnabled'] = settings.ENABLE_TWITTER
    if self.request.user.is_anonymous():
        #if not self.invitation or self.invitation.is_used():
        #    ret['invalid_code'] = True
        #   return ret
        if self.invitation and self.invitation.is_used():
            ret['invalid_code'] = True
            return ret
    ret['code'] = self.request.GET.get('code')
    return ret

def form_valid(self, form):
    ret = super(RegisterUserView, self).form_valid(form)
    if type(ret) == HttpResponseRedirect:
        if self.invitation:
            self.invitation.status = Invitation.STATUS_REGISTERED
            self.invitation.save()
            messages.add_message(self.request, messages.SUCCESS,
                                 _('Your account has been created. Welcome to DealCircle!'))
        else:
            messages.add_message(self.request, messages.SUCCESS, _('Your account has been updated successfully.'))
        user = authenticate(email=form.cleaned_data.get('email'), password=form.cleaned_data.get('password1'))
        if user and user.is_active:
            login(self.request, user)
    return ret

def get_success_url(self):
    if self.invitation and self.invitation.deal:
        return reverse('frontend_invitation_response', args=(self.invitation.code,))
    else:
        return reverse('frontend_profile')


def linkedin_info(user):
import oauth2 as oauth

consumer = oauth.Consumer(settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_KEY, settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_SECRET)
access_token = oauth.Token(key=user.linkedin_token, secret=user.linkedin_token_secret)
client = oauth.Client(consumer, access_token)
resp, content = client.request("http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(first-name,last-name,phone-numbers,picture-urls::(original))?format=json", "GET", "")
return resp, content
```

The custom user manager is this:

```
class DealCircleUserManager(BaseUserManager):
def create_user(self, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
    now = timezone.now()
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
    email = UserManager.normalize_email(email)
    user = self.model(email=email,
                      is_staff=False, is_active=True, is_superuser=False,
                      last_login=now, date_joined=now, **extra_fields)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    from postman.models import AddressBook
    AddressBook.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    return user

def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    u = self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
    u.is_staff = True
    u.is_active = True
    u.is_superuser = True
    u.save(using=self._db)
    from postman.models import AddressBook
    AddressBook.objects.get_or_create(user=u)
    return u
```

And the model is this:

```
class DealCircleUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
AVATAR_STORAGE_URL = 'https://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/%s'

avatar = models.ImageField(storage=s3, upload_to="users", null=True, blank=True)
avatar_thumb = ImageSpecField(cachefile_storage=s3, source='avatar',
                              processors=[ResizeToFill(*settings.THUMB_AVATAR)],
                              format='JPEG',
                              options={'quality': 60})
avatar_square_thumb = ImageSpecField(cachefile_storage=s3, source='avatar',
                                     processors=[SmartResize(*settings.THUMB_AVATAR_SQUARE)],
                                     format='JPEG',
                                     options={'quality': 60})
email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
address = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
city = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
country = models.ForeignKey(Country, verbose_name='country', null=True, blank=True)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
dob = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
bio = models.TextField(blank=True)
twitter_token = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
twitter_token_secret = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
linkedin_token = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
linkedin_token_secret = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
linkedin_connection_hash = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
google_access_token = jsonfield.JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
google_user_extras = jsonfield.JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
company = models.ForeignKey(Company, verbose_name='company', blank=True, null=True)
date_joined = models.DateField(null=True)
first_visit = models.BooleanField(default=True)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False,
                               help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin '
                               'site.'))
is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True,
                                help_text=_('Designates whether this user should be treated as '
                                'active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'))
objects = DealCircleUserManager()

def get_avatar_from_url(self, url):
    try:
        self.avatar.save(os.path.basename(url), ContentFile(urllib2.urlopen(url).read()))
        self.save()
        return True
    except Exception, e:
        return False

def get_avatar_url(self):
    return self.AVATAR_STORAGE_URL % (settings.BOTO_S3_BUCKET, self.avatar)

def get_full_name(self):
    full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
    return full_name.strip()

def get_short_name(self):
    return self.first_name

def get_dealinvestor(self, deal):
    return self.dealinvestor_set.get(deal=deal)

def is_email_valid(self):
    try:
        validate_email(self.email)
        return True
    except:
        return False

def disable_first_visit(self):
    self.first_visit = False
    self.save()
```

Comment: Please, provide UserCreationForm and CreateView code

Comment: Added the code, sorry for not adding it before ... slipped my mind

Comment: Do you have a customer manager for the users? What's your model look like for user?

Comment: OK, I've added the code for that as well. Now that I look at it again the problem might be the fact that we require the email to be unique? Is there a way to override the check for that?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your form does not validate : 
you should take a look at the clean method(s) of the  UserCreationForm and then do something like this (didn't tested) :

```
def clean_email(self):
    """
    First checking if the there is an invited user (User with same email exists and active==False ), if so validate the email.
    If the user exists and is active that means that the email is already in use, we raise a ValidationError
    If none of the above are True, the user does not exists at all, we should create it.
    """
    email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    if DealCircleUser.objects.filter(email=self.cleaned_data["email"], active=False).exists():
        return email
    elif DealCircleUser.objects.filter(email=self.cleaned_data["email"], active=True).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError(u'Email "%s" is already in use.' % email)
    return email
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that out as well.

Comment: Tried it, still the same error ... "Deal circle user with this Email already exists."

Comment: Sorry for the fast reply :/
Another solution would be to handle the registration form from another view, then you can determine if the user exists and redirect him to a CreatView (if does not exists) or an UpdateView if the user was invited, then you can set his account to active=True and add password